# REGEX for reaching a max amount of characters plus the end of the word (if applicable)

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex

I need to make a substring for text that is at max 100 characters long but if it ends in the middle of a word it needs to finish that word. I know seperatly it is

Max char (any character): `/^.{0,100}$/`

and end of a word `/^\w+*\b$/`

I am not sure how to combine the two to be more elegant.

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be done with a regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^.{0,100}(?:\B\w+)?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SoUoOL/2) with a `{0,10}` quantifier for brevity.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `.{0,100}`  - any 0 to 100 (as many as possible) chars other than line break chars (replace with `[\s\S]` if you need to match across lines)
- `(?:\B\w+)?` - an optional string of 1 or more word chars only matched if there is a non-word boundary after the string matched with `.{0,100}` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the RegExp is the better solution. So I propose to you a search base solution too.

```js
// 150 char string
const longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet enim vel augue feugiat rhoncus eu et lacus. Aenean ultricies tempus volutpat."

function getSubString(string, length){
  if(string.length <= length) return string;
  let cursor = length-1;
  while(!/[^\w]/.test(string[cursor]) || cursor === string.length) cursor++;
  return string.substr(0,cursor);
}

let subString = getSubString(longString,100);
console.log(subString);
console.log(subString.length);
```